# How to read Local JSON file in ionic V4?

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

```
this.http.get(‘assets/data/subtitles.json’).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
this.subtitles = data;
});
```

This is ionic v3 localJSON read code, I have used.

but ionic V3 type not supported to ionic V4

Comment: where did you import `http` from?  Also are you getting any error logs in console?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead.

```js
fetch('assets/data/subtitles.json').then(async res => {
  this.subtitles = await res.json();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can read the json as an import,

```js
import * as subtitleJson from 'assets/data/subtitles.json';
```

Typescript may complain about the import not matching your type, so casting it as `any` works,

```js
const subtitles = subtitleJson as any;
```